# ASP.NET Core Mvc upload image on form having (data-ajax)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am developing an WebApplicaiton this application is just adding product that hava image and update it.

**View**

```
@model EShopper.Dto.Product.ProductCommonDto

<div class="row" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:50px">
    <form data-ajax-url="@Url.Action("ProductSave","AdminProduct")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-complete="complete" data-ajax-loading="#loading">
        <div id="exTab3" class="container">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="2b">
                <h3>Picture Upload Page</h3>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Upload Image</label>
                    <input asp-for="ProductImage" class="form-control" type="file" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-sm-12">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ProductSave(ProductCommonDto productCommonDto)
        {
            var result = _productProcessService.ProductSave(productCommonDto);
            return Json(result);
        }
```

**Model**

```
public class ProductCommonDto
    {
        public ProductDto Product { get; set; }
        public IFormFile ProductImage { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem is, when I trying to upload image it returning ( Null ) in backend.

If i remove ( data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" ), it can upload the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo , you could refer to:

Model:

```
public class ProductCommonDto
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public IFormFile ProductImage { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]     
public async Task<IActionResult> ProductSave(ProductCommonDto productCommonDto)
{
        //the stuff you want
}
```

View:

```
@model ProductCommonDto

<div class="row" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:50px">
<form data-ajax-url="@Url.Action("ProductSave","Home")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-complete="complete" data-ajax-loading="#loading">
        <div id="exTab3" class="container">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="2b">
                <h3>Picture Upload Page</h3>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Upload Image</label>
                    <input asp-for="ProductImage" class="form-control" type="file" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-sm-12">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

}
```

Comment: Still returning Null in backend :(

Comment: Could you share the complete demo so that we can review and debug the code ? It is a little difficult to reproduce the issue based on the existing code snippet .

Comment: I updated the question, and all detail you want to debug the code. I will be so thankful if you can debug the code and fix it :)

Comment: @Wampir32  , check my updated above. [Here](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-xuelc_microsoft_com/EURyLtM8-YNKkhco4VJhuUwBjcQZ7xxAyn_8lQZYAuqAiA?e=p2gheB) is my test project , you can check the difference between yours if you still have any issue.

Comment: I can't open the site.

Comment: Refer to [this github](https://github.com/SherryCXL/Demo1) which is my demo link.

Comment: it seem all thing are same, but still returning null on my project, Do you think it is about .net core version??

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the form generated by Razor and send it to backend in IFormFile type.
See the example for that below:

**View**

```
@model CreateVM
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "ImageResource", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{
    ...
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageURL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="file" name="productImg"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    ...
}
```

**Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CreateVM create, IFormFile productImg)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (productImg != null)
                {
                    //Any logic you would like to do with image
                }
            }
            return View(create);
        }
```

In this scenario, you will pass the image directly to your backend for further actions, rather than uploading it by JavaScript.

Comment: HttpPostedFileBase in asp.net core 2.2 ??

Comment: Mismatched with IFormFile type

Comment: I tried IFormFile but it returning NULL, the problem is when i delete data-ajax i can upload the file ...

Comment: Do your image parameter name are the same in your View and in Controller when using IFormFile?

Comment: Yeah it same, i deleted the ( data-ajax in form tag ) it uploaded, but when i use ( data-ajax ) then try to upload file it returning ( NULL )

Comment: I have the same issue right now. did you resolved it?